# Aggregation of Tuples into Single Known Value with Combinatorics ?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, optimization

I am not a math wizard so please bear with me in my question - I do not know the correct terminology for the problem that I am trying to solve.

I have a set of values representing lengths of an object. 
I receive a large number. I now need a simple model to resolve how many of what lengths will fit into large number.

For example if I have the following lengths

> 5, 8, 10, 12.5, 15, 18, 20

(They can be different this is just an example).

I receive a value of 104 (just an example it changes).

> I need to be able to fit the various length objects (favoring larger
>   over smaller) into 104 in this case I would have an array of
>   20,20,20,20,8,8,8 as a result.

If I were to receive something such as 107.5 (I would like the remainder as the final object even if it does not fit.)

1: What is a mathematical model for solving this problem?

2: What is the mathematical term for this kind of function ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I would like the remainder as the final object even if it does not fit" ?

Comment: @Kuifje if there is a remainder because there is no possible combinations of lengths to make the whole number - I would like all lengths and then this remainder value as the last value in the set. I do not wish to drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [change making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

Do you assume that you can take a fraction of the last item? If so:

Let $M$ be your maximum value. You can order your items $i_i$ of length $\ell_i$ by non increasing values of $\ell_i$. Without loss of generality, let $(i_1,i_2,...,i_n)$ be this ordered list. Take the first object of this ordered list, and select it $\lfloor M/\ell_1 \rfloor$ times (the funny brackets represent the floor function). If the remainder is $0$, you are done. Otherwise, replace $M$ by the remainder of $M/\ell_1$, and select the second item $\lfloor M/\ell_2 \rfloor$ times. Repeat until $M=0$.

With your example, this would yield $20,20,20,20,20,\frac{8}{2}$.

Comment: ℓ1 in M/ℓ1 would that be equivalent to one of the defined values in my list of lengths or the length of one item in my list of items ? 
The fractions would be fine as long as I do not miss a possible whole representation - here the 8/2 (is 4 ) and the last 20 is 24  which yields 3 items of 8 length. If there was no other possibility to resolve then the fraction is fine.

Comment: Yes $\ell$ represents your lengths and $M$ your "received value".